# Kotlin Unresolved Reference: with

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin, picasso

I have already tried invalidating caches. Clean build and rebuild project also done.
But I still keep getting unresolved reference: with
I'm using the Picasso library and my other activities are working fine. Picasso library has been implemented in the gradle.
The language version is 1.2 Android Studio

Code:

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.net.Uri
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import chatonapp.project.com.chatonapp.R
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage
import id.zelory.compressor.Compressor
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_settings.*

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.File

class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var mDatabase: DatabaseReference? = null
    var mCurrentUser: FirebaseUser? = null
    var mStorageRef: StorageReference? = null
    var GALLERY_ID: Int = 1

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)


        mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference


        var userId = mCurrentUser!!.uid

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                .child("Users")
                .child(userId)

        mDatabase!!.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{

            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
                var displayName = dataSnapshot!!.child("display_name").value
                var image = dataSnapshot!!.child("image").value.toString()
                var userStatus = dataSnapshot!!.child("status").value
                var thumbnail = dataSnapshot!!.child("thumb_image").value

                settinsDisplayName.text = displayName.toString()
                settingsStatusText.text = userStatus.toString()

                if (!image!!.equals("default")) {
                    Picasso.with(applicationContext)
                            .load(image)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.profile_img)
                            .into(settingsProfileID)
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseErrorSnapshot: DatabaseError?) {

            }

        })


        settingsChangeStatus.setOnClickListener {
            var intent = Intent(this, StatusActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("status", settingsStatusText.text.toString().trim())
            startActivity(intent)

        }

        settingsChangeImgBtn.setOnClickListener {
            var galleryIntent = Intent()
            galleryIntent.type = "image/*"
            galleryIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "SELECT_IMAGE"), GALLERY_ID)
        }

    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_ID
                && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            var image: Uri = data!!.data

            CropImage.activity(image)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(this)

        }

        if (requestCode === CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            val result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data)

            if (resultCode === Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                val resultUri = result.uri

                var userId = mCurrentUser!!.uid
                var thumbFile = File(resultUri.path)

                var thumbBitmap = Compressor(this)
                        .setMaxWidth(200)
                        .setMaxHeight(200)
                        .setQuality(65)
                        .compressToBitmap(thumbFile)



                var byteArray = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                thumbBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,  100,
                        byteArray)
                var thumbByteArray: ByteArray
                thumbByteArray = byteArray.toByteArray()

                var filePath = mStorageRef!!.child("chat_profile_images")
                        .child(userId + ".jpg")

                //Create another directory for thumbimages ( smaller, compressed images)
                var thumbFilePath = mStorageRef!!.child("chat_profile_images")
                        .child("thumbs")
                        .child(userId + ".jpg")


                filePath.putFile(resultUri)
                        .addOnCompleteListener{
                            task: Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> ->
                            if (task.isSuccessful) {


                                var donwloadUrl = task.result.downloadUrl.toString()


                                var uploadTask: UploadTask = thumbFilePath
                                        .putBytes(thumbByteArray)

                                uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener{
                                    task: Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> ->
                                    var thumbUrl = task.result.downloadUrl.toString()

                                    if (task.isSuccessful) {


                                        var updateObj = HashMap<String, Any>()
                                        updateObj.put("image", donwloadUrl)
                                        updateObj.put("thumb_image", thumbUrl)


                                        mDatabase!!.updateChildren(updateObj)
                                                .addOnCompleteListener {
                                                    task: Task<Void> ->
                                                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                                                        Toast.makeText(this, "Profile Image Saved!",
                                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                                .show()

                                                    }else {

                                                    }
                                                }

                                    }else {

                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
            }else if (resultCode === CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                val error = result.error
                Log.d("Error", error.toString())
            }
        }

    }


}
```

The problem happens here: Picasso.with

```
 if (!image!!.equals("default")) {
                    Picasso.with(applicationContext)
                            .load(image)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.profile_img)
                            .into(settingsProfileID)
                }
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: did you manage to find out a solution for this?

Comment: Similar Thing is happening with lot of other libraries as well. Seems entirely random to me. Currently im not able to get Google Play services. This started with the integration of kotlin in our projects

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem tonight, After looking at the Picasso site I noticed that .with is not used anymore. .get() works fine. Try something like this.

```
Picasso.get()
    .load(url)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
    .into(imageView);
```

My code looked like this

```
val thumbnailImage = holder.view.imageView_Video_Thumbnail
Picasso.get().load(movieTitle.imageUrl).into(thumbnailImage)
```

Hope that helps someone.